# Where do I put the root dialog for a Microsoft Bot Service

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am a complete N00b when it comes to creating a bot service. I have generated my bot using the Basic Template. In the template code the run.csx file starts the code with the

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
```

method. There are many people that point to the [PizzaBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot) for reference but I can not tell what code is called first to kick off the Dialog Flow. Where would I start the dialog chain ? Do I replace this logic

```
....

case ActivityTypes.Message:
          await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
            break;
....
```

with

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
```

or somewhere completely different. Just trying to figure out where to create the root dialog to start the process and all the samples I have seen do not have a run.csx and I have no idea how the service is getting started.

Comment: I think everything is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-template-basic
So yes it is in the `case ActivityTypes.Message:` block

Comment: Do you want to execute the `EchoDialog()` rather than the `RootDialog()`?  Or do you want to use both of the dialogs?

Comment: Nicolas gave the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @NicolasR why not post your comment as a complete answer, so that can be checked as the favourite one?